# C: How to input only int data from a text file of unknown size

Tags: c, input, text-files

```
void inputData()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("input_001.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        exit(FILE_FAILED_TO_OPEN);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); //set position to end of file
    int size = ftell(fp);
    if(size == 0)
    {
        exit(PARSING_ERROR_EMPTY_FILE);
    }
    int i;
    char *input;
    char *errPtr = NULL; 
    char *data;
    fgets(input, 64, fp);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        strtol(input[i], *errPtr, 10);
        //testing the output
        printf("%d\n", input[i]);
    }      

    fclose(fp);
    if(fclose(fp) != 0)
    {
        exit(FILE_FAILED_TO_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I am trying to input data from a text file of unknown size into an array and keep only the integers. The format of the text file is one number per line and there can be any number of lines. I have included my attempt at trying to input the data, but my coding was not going so well. I want to use fgets() and then strtol() to convert the lines I get from fgets() into integers and put them in an array so I can work with that data. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Um, you wanna maybe uncomment one part of that, so people can tell which part to critique? Cause it looks like you've got at least two attempts there. I would recommend simply having a short line buffer and reading the lines into it one by one.

Comment: Will do, hold up one sec. *It is now edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated any space for `input` to point to. I saw your
earlier version had a `malloc`; you can use that, or just a `char`
array.

Did you mean to use `data`? Because you're not, yet.

`fgets` reads at most one line at a time, so you need to put your reads
in a loop.

You appear to be converting the string to a number multiple times. For
instance, if the first line were `"12345"`, this code would get `12345`,
then `2345`, `345`, etc. This was presumably not your intention.

You're incrementing `i` up to `size`. `size` is the file size and might
be quite large, but you only read a maximum of 64 characters into the
buffer. (Or would have, if space had been allocated.)

In short, this code is very confused and I recommend starting over from
scratch. Decide whether you want to read the entire file at once, or one
line at a time; I recommend the latter, it takes less memory and is
simpler. If you want to store them in an array, you can do that with
`malloc` and then `realloc` as needed to grow the array dynamically.

Comment: I shall start over on the code and I'll edit my post. I want to read the file one line at time. Do you think an array is a good way to store the data?

Comment: Depends on what you plan to do with it. Random access, sorting? Array. Sequential access only? Array or linked list. Just going to calculate something? You may not need to store it at all.

Comment: I'm given that I'll have two files of integers and I have to figure out which numbers appear in both files and print every number that occurs in both files in sorted order.

Comment: Then I'd recommend two arrays, sort, and traverse together. If you're on Unix you can check your answer by sorting each file, then `comm -12 file1 file2`.

Comment: I have completed my program. I went the malloc and realloc route. Here it is: https://missouri.box.com/s/lz7mre04btslqwh63dq31dm99ghdygzu

Answer (score 0):

do not use strtol, use atoi instead.
and use a loop to read the lines.

just a quick answer:

```
int count = 0;
while( fgets (input, 64, fp) != NULL )
{
count++;
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
int* arr = new int[count];

count = 0;
while( fgets (input, 64, fp) != NULL )
{
int a =atoi(input);
arr[count++] = a;
}
```

Comment: sorry about that, use malloc instead.                                                                 int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I tried using some of your code and I was able to find out how many lines were in my file which was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many lines are in the file, you have a few options:

1. Loop through the file, counting the number of lines (call it `nlines`). Then declare the array `int numbers[nlines]`.
2. Use a linked list instead of an array to store the numbers.
3. Dynamically allocate blocks of an array.

As for reading the integer data itself, something like this would work if you decide to go with the first option:

```
void inputData(const char* fname, const unsigned int nlines)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int numbers[nlines];

    double d = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", &d);
    int i = 0;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        numbers[i++] = (int)floor(d);
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &d);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```